# Create custom SDK for React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

What i want to achieve is something like creating my own SDK like what react-native-fbsdk or [rn-onesignal-sdk](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/react-native-sdk-setup) provides , so that those functionalities can be implemented in the react native project.

Basic questions :

1. Where to start from? Like what are the pre-requisites?
2. Native coding is required i believe for this functionality?

Any explanation or any such experience in such would be of great help .

Answer (score 4):

> Where to start from? Like what are the pre-requisites?

You can use a template like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-module-template). It includes an `example` project which is basically an app that you can use to test integration of your native module and to quickly iterate on it.

> Native coding is required i believe for this functionality?

Only if you need to use platform-specific functionality, or provide bindings to some pre-existing native library. Both examples you mentioned do exactly that – because they have native SDKs that can be used in non-RN apps, and they provide React Native bindings for them.

If your library is just business logic + some networking, and you don't intend it to be used in non-RN apps, you can do it all in JS. No need for native code. If you choose to go with the template that I have linked above, there are instructions how to use it to create a pure JS React Native library.

I'll be happy to update my answer if you can share some concrete requirements of what you want your SDK to do.